# How to maintain state of a layout in jade in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

My layout.jade looks like

```
doctype html
html 
  body
    block menu

    block pagecontent
```

and index.jade has the following code

```
    extends layout

block menu
    body
        h1 #{menuData}
```

and somepage.jade has

```
    extends layout

block pagecontent
    h3  user demo page
```

Now the scenario is first time I will load the index page and from then for all the requests i need to change only the only the pagecontent block. Since on the first request i loaded all the menu. So for all the other requests i need to write something like

```
res.render('somepage')
```

then it should load the index page with menucontent and this page content. How to do this effectively ?

The idea is like in Asp.net we have a master page and content page. While redirecting we will redirect to child pages with the same loaded master page. I need similar approach.

**UPDATE**

As mentioned in the answer i can do that way, but say i have twenty pages. So while rendering every page i need to pass the layout with the menuData (may be stored in a variable). Thats fine. But still any other way to do that or is that the only fine way ?

I am very new to nodejs please help me on this.